# Using enclosed by in hbase

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hbase

I have data in tsv form and I want to insert it into hbase, the problem is each field is enclosed by "'" (a single quote).

How can I provide it in the import command:

> hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv
>   -Dimporttsv.bulk.output=output1 -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,data:employee_id,data:employee_name,data:designation,data:telephone_number,data:artist_mbid,
>   employees /emp

I found that options available with hbase are:
in 
https://hbase.apache.org/book.html

```
importtsv
Other options that may be specified with -D include:
  -Dimporttsv.skip.bad.lines=false - fail if encountering an invalid line
  '-Dimporttsv.separator=|' - eg separate on pipes instead of tabs
  -Dimporttsv.timestamp=currentTimeAsLong - use the specified timestamp for the import
  -Dimporttsv.mapper.class=my.Mapper - A user-defined Mapper to use instead of org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TsvImporterMapper
```

> I am searching something like equivalent of mysql's command: LOAD DATA
>   INFILE 'output' INTO TABLE employee  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
>   OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

Answer (score 1):

I assume your data is as below

'value1'    'value2'    'value3'

So instead of using tab as separator, I tested using ('    '). Single quote, tab, single quote using -Dimporttsv.separator. But this did not work, because ImportTsv will accept separator which is of single byte length.

So looks like, based on documentation, you need to implement your own mapper using -Dimporttsv.mapper.class similar to ImportTsv, and tweaking as per your need. See [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hbase/hbase/0.89.20100924-28/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/ImportTsv.java) for basic idea of ImportTsv.

After all, you are running a map reduce, so you are not loosing latency